# How to add object to arraylist

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I'm having problems adding objects to the list. I have a list of floors, each floor has rooms . I can add floor but i don't know how to add rooms to the floor list.

I've tried to get floor[index] or id but doesn't work . What should i do right now ?

```
export default class HomeWork extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            floors: [
                {
                    floorId: 1, name: 'floor1', rooms: [
                        { roomId: 1, name: 'new room' },
                        { roomId: 2, name: 'new room' }]
                },
                {
                    floorId: 2, name: 'floor2', rooms: [
                        { roomId: 1, name: 'new room' },]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    addRoom(index) {
        const RoomArr = [...this.state.floors[index].rooms]
        RoomArr.push(
            { id: 2, roomName: 'New Room' });
        this.setState({
            // Stuck here too
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.parent}>
                <View >
                    <FlatList
                        data={(this.state.floors)}
                        renderItem={({ item }) => {
                            return (
                                <View>
                                    <View >
                                        <Text>Floor {item.floorNumber}</Text>
                                        <Text>Room per Floor:</Text>
                                        <Text >{item.rooms.length}</Text>
                                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={(index) => { this.addRoom(index) }}>
                                            <Image source={Images.plusIcon}></Image>
                                        </TouchableOpacity>
                                    </View>
                                    <FlatList
                                        data={(item.rooms)}
                                        numColumns={4}
                                        renderItem={({ item }) => {
                                            return (
                                                <View>
                                                    <Text>{item.roomName}</Text>
                                                </View>
                                            )
                                        }}
                                    ></FlatList>
                                </View>
                            )
                        }}
                    ></FlatList>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

I expect at least i can get index of floor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the floors with the spread operator, update your particular floor based on index, then use `setState` with the floors again like this:

```
addRoom(index) {
    let floors = [...this.state.floors];
    floors[index].rooms.push({ id: 2, roomName: 'New Room' });
    this.setState({ floors })
}
```

Comment: ohhh i forgot put index into renderItem T_T so i fixed and it's works . btw thank you for your time !